# How to create a jQuery Toggle only on selected list item

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, toggle

I have a list with a default active class. When I click on the "select me" button I want the active class to change to that button in that li which was clicked on and remove the previous class.

It does do this, but it adds the active class on every list item too.

How can I get it to toggle the class only on the li which the button is clicked on?

Not sure if my css is correct, or it can all be done via jQuery?

Here's a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/capymq5j/1/

```js
$('.select-offer').on('click', function(e) {
  // $('.button-group').not(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
  // $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');

  $('.button-group').toggleClass("active nothng");
  // $(".button-group").removeClass("active");
  // $(this).find(".button-group").toggleClass("active");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.button-group {
  & .cta {
    display: none;
  }
}

.button-group.active {
  & .cta {
    display: block;
  }
  & .select-offer {
    display: none;
  }
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="button-group active">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM navigation relative to `this`. So it should be `$(this).closest(".button-group")` to select just the button group containing the clicked button.

You can remove the `active` class from all the buttons, then add the class to the selected element.

```js
$('.select-offer').on('click', function(e) {
  $('button-group').removeClass('active').addClass('nothing');
  $(this).closest('.button-group').addClass('active').removeClass('nothing');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.button-group {
  & .cta {
    display: none;
  }
}

.button-group.active {
  & .cta {
    display: block;
  }
  & .select-offer {
    display: none;
  }
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="button-group active">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Kind of there. But i need it where when i click "select me" on another li i need only this one to show the cta 1 and cta 2 buttons. All others should then be inactive and so on

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.select-offer').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.button-group .cta {
    display: none;
}

.button-group.active .cta {
    display: block;
}
.button-group.active.select-offer {
    display: none;
}


ul,li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul{display:flex;}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 12px;
  height:100%;
}
.button-group{
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="button-group">
      <a href="#" class="select-offer">Select me</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta">cta 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Please try this**

Comment: check this answer @John. Almost solved. Any issue comment me

Comment: I ```scss``` changed to ```css``` for using this snippet to show as a working demo